# Mod Rewrite Error In htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm wanting to redirect my url using RewriteRule in .htaccess but it's gining me an Internal Server Error.

I would like:

```
articles.php?cat=categorya
```

To become:

```
articles/categorya
```

So I'm using the following code:

```
DirectoryIndex articles.php
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule     ^articles/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    articles.php    [NC,L]    # Articles
RewriteRule     ^articles/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    articles.php?cat=$1    [NC,L]    # Articles Categories
```

However this gives me the error.  Does anyone know why this could be happening?  I've tested htacces `DirectoryIndex` on it's own and that works fine so I'm sure htaccess is enabled.

## LoadModule is uncommented & Apache restarted. No change to the error though.  Is there a solution?

Comment: The server’s error log knows why it’s happening – so go check that.

Comment: And why are you trying to match the exact same thing twice?

Comment: Okay, checking that I see, `[Sat Oct 10 15:57:54 2015] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/AppServ/www/***/***/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteRule', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`

Comment: @CBroe And #LoadModule is uncommented & Apache restarted. No change to the error though.  Is there a solution?

Comment: Maybe you’re just missing a `RewriteEngine On` …?

Comment: Added that back in but it's still not working.  Even doing something like `RewriteRule articles.php about.php` shows me an error.

Comment: In Fact @CBroe, just having `RewriteEngine On` in the htaccess file shows the 500 error.  Really not sure how to fix this one

Comment: Check what `AllowOverride` is set to. You need `All` or `FileInfo` so that you can use the directives mod_rewrite provides. (But the error message rather sounds as if mod_rewrite module was not enabled. _Double_-check that.)

Comment: @CBroe My httpd.conf file shows that everything is uncommented and I've enabled AllowOverride but when I check the phpinfo file there is no mention of mod_rewrite in the Apache loaded modules.  Where is the problem if the httpd is edited correctly?